# Mac application menu for java program that also runs on windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing

I am working on a program that will work on both Windows and Mac machines. I found this [link](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/handling-main-mac-menu-in-swing-application) that explains how to implement the application menu on a Mac. But since it uses mac specific classes for interfaces I am not sure how to write the class so it compiles in Windows as well.

Comment: As an aside, without having to have the OSX JDK (which I don't think actually is supported anymore, also, all of the classes which that site talks about are deprecated), do `System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");` to put your `JMenuBar` into the bar at the top of the screen, where it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have googled a little further.  Found this class on a [old google group](https://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2004/Jun/msg00118.html).  Just had to extend it to include Preferences.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class OSXAdapter implements InvocationHandler {

    private OSXQuitListener _quitListener;
    private OSXAboutListener _aboutListener;
    private OSXPreferenceListener _perferenceListener;

    /**
     * creates this adapter, only does stuff when we're on a mac, if it's unable to
     * register the quit adapter, then we throw an exception.
     *
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     * @throws SecurityException
     * @throws NoSuchMethodException
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public OSXAdapter() throws ClassNotFoundException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        // get's the os name
        String vers = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

        // only attempt to the do the following if we're on a mac
        if (vers.indexOf("mac") != -1) {
            Class quitHandlerClass = Class.forName("com.apple.mrj.MRJQuitHandler");
            Class aboutHandlerClass = Class.forName("com.apple.mrj.MRJAboutHandler");
            Class prefHandlerClass = Class.forName("com.apple.mrj.MRJPrefsHandler");

            Class mrjapputilsClass = Class.forName("com.apple.mrj.MRJApplicationUtils");
            Object methodHandler = Proxy.newProxyInstance(quitHandlerClass.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { quitHandlerClass, aboutHandlerClass, prefHandlerClass }, this);

            Method appUtilsObj = mrjapputilsClass.getMethod("registerQuitHandler", new Class[] { quitHandlerClass });
            appUtilsObj.invoke(null, new Object[] { methodHandler });

            appUtilsObj = mrjapputilsClass.getMethod("registerAboutHandler", new Class[] { aboutHandlerClass });
            appUtilsObj.invoke(null, new Object[] { methodHandler });

            appUtilsObj = mrjapputilsClass.getMethod("registerPrefsHandler", new Class[] { prefHandlerClass });
            appUtilsObj.invoke(null, new Object[] { methodHandler });

        }
    }

    /**
     * registers an about dialog. When the os x system fires the event which
     * triggers an about class
     * 
     * @param listener
     */
    public void setAboutListener(OSXAboutListener listener) {
        _aboutListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * registers an preference listener. When the os x fires the preference event this will be
     * fired.
     * 
     * @param listener
     */
    public void setPerferenceListener(OSXPreferenceListener listener) {
        _perferenceListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * register an quit listener. When the os x fires the quit event this will be
     * fired.
     *
     * @param listener
     */
    public void setQuitListener(OSXQuitListener listener) {
        _quitListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * @see java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler#invoke(java.lang.Object,
     *      java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[])
     */
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method meth, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (meth.getName().equals("handleQuit")) {
            if (null != _quitListener) {
                _quitListener.handleQuit();
            }
        } else if (meth.getName().equals("handleAbout")) {
            if (null != _aboutListener) {
                _aboutListener.handleAbout();
            }
        } else if (meth.getName().equals("handlePrefs")) {
            if (null != _perferenceListener) {
                _perferenceListener.handlePrefs();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
    * listener which listens to the about event from the os x
    * system
    *
    * @author Chris Shorrock
    */
    public interface OSXAboutListener {

    /**
    * handles the about display event.
    */
    public void handleAbout();

    }



    /**
    * this listener is fired when the os x system quits
    *
    * @author Chris Shorrock
    */
    public interface OSXQuitListener {

    /**
    * this method is called when os x tells this application
    * to quit.
    */
    public void handleQuit();
    }



    /**
    * this listener is fired when the os x system fires preferences
    *
    * @author Chris Shorrock
    */
    public interface OSXPreferenceListener {

    /**
    * this method is called when os x tells this application
    * to open preferences.
    */
    public void handlePrefs();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it still supported with newer Java versions on MAC OS X?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend JavaFx. The interface will look like windows on windows and like mac on mac. You can use normal java for everything that works on every machine. In addition, the Jfx Scene builder can help you with designing the application.

Comment: Actually, a JavaFX based interface won't look like Windows Metro or Mac Aqua, it will look like [Modena](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/) (unless you use something like [AquaFX](http://aquafx-project.com)).  But, you are right that JavaFX will provide a "Mac application menu for java program that also runs on windows" if you use a [`MenuBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuBar.html#useSystemMenuBarProperty) with the `useSystemMenuBarProperty` set to true.  Anyway, the question is tagged Swing, so JavaFX is probably not wanted.